# Can't run "npm install" without deleting node_modules after upgrading to NPM 5.4.1

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, fsevents

I've upgraded NPM from 5.3.0 to 5.4.1 and after that, it seems that the command *npm install* works only if I've removed *node_modules*. When I try to rerun the installation, I'm getting the following error message. (After that, if I again remove *node_modules*, the command *run install* works - **once**.)

> PS C:\source\website> npm install
>   npm ERR! path   C:\source\website\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba\package.jsonvet.Web
>   npm ERR! code EPERM
>   npm ERR! errno -4048
>   npm ERR! syscall unlink
>   npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink   'C:\source\website\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba\package.json'
>   npm ERR!  {
>   Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink   'C:\source\website\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba\package.json'
>   npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink  \'C:\source\website\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba\package.json\'',
>   npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
>   npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
>   npm ERR!   path:
>    'C:\source\website\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba\package.json' }
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\butt\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-09-13T16_42_26_030Z-debug.log
>   PS C:\source\website>

Nothing else has changed in my setup, as far I'm aware. My environment is Windows 10 and Node 8.2.1. The behavior seems to be consistent on several computers.

I notice that during the re-runs of the installation, there's a lot of waiting time, like if the installer gets stuck, on the following stage of it.

> added 995 packages in 29.671s
>   PS C:\source\website> npm install
>   [            ......] - postinstall: sill doSerial postinstall 686

I have no clue on how to proceed with this. Is *fsevents* to blame at all? I recall that it produced warnings but still transpiling fine in earlier versions.

There's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087741/npm-5-4-1-install-uninstall-all-failing) on this theme but precisely covering my issue. I can't decide if it's just different working of the same problem or if it's two separate troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running Win 10 and recognized the same issue. The resolution was to downgrade to 5.3. I also noticed that 5.4.0 worked on our build server (TFS 2017).

```
npm install --global npm@5.3.0
```

One thing that provided no help at all was all the stuff about admin mode. We lost a few hours reconfiguring and resetting the build pipe using admin rights.

There was a crucial module that required 5.4.1 for some reason, not relevant which in this particular case. We resolved it by separate steps in the pipe - one that reused a pre-built version and one that was dynamically assembled.

Also, I'd not worry about it. In a few days or so, there's got to be an update and the issue will be resolved. Until then - downgrade to 5.3 is the hack-around we used.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common issue many found with npm 5.4 , only option at this point is to downgrade npm back to 5.3

```
npm i -g npm@5.3.0
```

For more updates follow this thread.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18380

P.S : you can also try using `npm cache clean --force` after the downgrade and try installing 5.4 again with `npm i -g npm@5.4.1` or `npm install --no-optional` if you really need npm 5.4 to get your work done.

Answer (score 0):

Dont' know what is causing issue but you can try several solutions that worked for others :

- 1

  `npm cache clean`

  `npm install`
- 2

  `npm i`
- 3

  Run your command prompt by right clicking as choose `open as administrator` and then run your command

Hope this help you.